# PHP Increment alphanumeric string

Tags: php, sql-server, string, increment, alphanumeric

I working on a page where the user will see a table using datatables with a set of their data.
They need to have the option to put their own numbering, could be just numbers or alphanumeric and the increment as well.

So it will have two inputs one for the starting number that could be anything they want like:
`1`, `A01`, `01`, `A01M` and the list goes on. So the combinations could be endless.

And the list goes on, now the tricky bit is the increment. The user need to have the option to set the increment to be anything numeric and since it might have characters at the end which shouldn't change, the `$n++` to increment alphanumeric string wont work here.

I've been googling around but the only ones I've found are for specific cases or to do the autoincrement using the `++`.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Tried using a prefix, suffix and then an auto-increment? Does that work? e.g 'A01' is a prefix and 'M' is the suffix for a series then you add a n-digit number in between which gets incremented. You may have to use a different table for maintaining this series if it is MySQL.

Comment: If I understood you correctly you could use regex to get the numbers and increment them and put them back to string.

Comment: @Robert Sound like the way I might end up going but I'm terrible with RegEx.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not case-sensitive, you can use `base_convert($string, 36,10)`. This will transform a string into a int (considering the string to be a number in base 36).

```
$var = base_convert('azz',36,10);
echo base_convert($var,10,36).PHP_EOL; $var+=1;
echo base_convert($var,10,36).PHP_EOL; $var+=1;
echo base_convert($var,10,36).PHP_EOL;
```

Will give you :

```
azz
b00
b01
```

But be aware that 6 caracters will already give you 36^6-1 ~ 2 Billion possibilities which is around the value of a simple interger!

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you may use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
function increment($string)
{
   return preg_replace_callback('/^([^0-9]*)([0-9]+)([^0-9]*)$/', function($m)
   {
      return $m[1].str_pad($m[2]+1, strlen($m[2]), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).$m[3];
   }, $string);
}
```

[`str_pad()`](http://php.net/str_pad) is needed since we may have leading zeros, which are significant if speaking about strings. Some examples:

```
var_dump(increment('2000000000'));//string(10) "2000000001"
var_dump(increment('A040'));      //string(4) "A041"
var_dump(increment('A15MM'));     //string(5) "A16MM"
var_dump(increment('PY999LKD'));  //string(9) "PY1000LKD"
```

Note, that this function will leave ambiguous cases untouched:

```
var_dump(increment('N008P91F'));  //string(8) "N008P91F"
```

Comment: In PHP 5.2 that would be:
`function increment($string)
{
  function subfunc($m) {
    return $m[1].str_pad($m[2]+1, strlen($m[2]), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).$m[3];
  }
  return preg_replace_callback('/^([^0-9]*)([0-9]+)([^0-9]*)$/', 'subfunc', $string);
}`

Answer (score 0):

this regex should work as well `'/\d+/'`